# ASP.NET, Setting default screen size to 1024x768

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

Forgive me, I am new to developing on webpages in general. I must set a webpage such that its default height is aimed at users using a display of 1024px * 768px. If the contents of the page are larger vertically than what can fit in the space provided once this change is done, the page should still expand vertically so that the text can be displayed.

This is one of the requirements to my practice project for a job I have just started. I am unsure if what I've done works, or even how it can be tested. Within the  I have:

```
<body onload="window.resizeTo(1024,768)"> ... </body>
```

Is this correct? I see no noticeable change on my screen upon testing this.

Answer (score 5):

Try to not do things that will annoy your users, resizing their window, pop-ups, pop-unders, and sound are all good ways to do this.  The less you impose on your users, the better.  Everyone has their own browsing habits, and when the site you go to *tells you* how to browse it, it feels obnoxious.

What I would recommend instead is to set a width of a containing element to 1024px.  In the web world, it is expected to have some vertical scroll, and horizontal scroll is discouraged (aside from designs that explicitly account for this, which is very rare).

```
/* in a css file */
#container {
    width: 1024px; /* explicitly set the width to 1024px */
    margin: 0 auto; /* this will center your container */
}

<!-- in your HTML (after referencing the css file) -->
<div id="container">
    <p>Bla bla bla this is my content</p>
</div>
```